# In Java, is a conditional expression a thread safe operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition, conditional-expressions

I'm wondering if a conditional expression is a thread safe operation in Java.
E.g.:

```
return (mObject != null ? mObject.toString() : "null");
```

So, my question is: If two threads can change mObject, is this code thread safe, or does the developer need to handle any race conditions?

Comment: Sounds like you should synchronize the whole method if mObject is mutable and shared.

Comment: The short answer, related to the conditional ternary operator you present, is no. Recall that even an affectation like int i = 0 is not "thread-safe" (thus Atomic* classes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's absolutely not thread-safe. You could definitely get a `NullPointerException` here. It's easy to fix, of course:

```
Object tmp = mObject;
return tmp != null ? tmp.toString() : "null";
```

Or, even more easily in this particular case:

```
return String.valueOf(mObject);
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, if you've really got two threads racing to update a value with no synchronization, that's *probably* a sign of bigger problems... but I only tried to answer the question you specifically asked.

Comment: isn't it a little too simply? this solution prevents NPE, but isn't it still possible that tmp is null mObject being changed after the copy was made, hence the value returned is not the actually value of mObject

Comment: @G.Z. The OP did not say anything about the memory visibility so I think the answer clearly answers the question.

Comment: @G.Z.: Have edited my answer to indicate potential further problems.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not thread safe, just make a local copy of `mObject`:

```
final Object local = mObject;
return (local != null ? local.toString() : "null");
```

Answer (score 2):

The developer needs to make sure they have a consistent view of any field which can be changed.

This might be a solution

```
Object mObject = this.mObject;
return mObject != null ? mObject.toString() : "null";
```

or

```
return String.valueOf(mObject);
```

or

```
return ""+mObject;
```